# json doesnt show anything with php query

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

Im certanley new on this, but I´m Trying to solve this problem.

I have to repeat a lot this kind of query to an sql server. My problem is when i call the php from html, the getjason function or any other method return any data.

The php

```html
<?php 
function getArraySQL()
{
$dsn = "prueba";
$connect = odbc_connect( $dsn, '', '' );

$query = " SELECT hist_statusevents.reason, Sum(hist_statusevents.duration/3600) AS 'Duracion'
FROM hist_statusevents, hist_eqmtlist, hist_exproot
WHERE hist_exproot.shiftindex = hist_statusevents.shiftindex AND hist_statusevents.shiftindex = hist_eqmtlist.shiftindex AND hist_statusevents.eqmt = hist_eqmtlist.eqmtid AND (hist_eqmtlist.eqmtid='SVEDALA') AND hist_statusevents.category In ('2')
GROUP BY hist_statusevents.reason
ORDER BY Duracion DESC";

if(!$rs = odbc_exec($connect, $query)) die();

$rawdata = array();

$i=0;

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs))
{
$rawdata[$i] = $row;
$i++;
}

odbc_close( $connect );
return $rawdata;
}

@$myarray =getArraySQL($query);
echo json_encode($myarray);
```

The HTML and getJson

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON('php.php', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
          $('ul').append('<li Reason="' + reason + '">' + Duration + '</li>');
        });
      });
    });
  </script>



  <ul></ul>

</body>

</html>


</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Any error in `console`?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Just discovered the console on Chrome...

Uncaught ReferenceError: reason is not defined

Comment: This is what I get whe I run the php

[
{
reason: "211.0",
Duracion: "3.6302777701057494"
},
{
reason: "201.0",
Duracion: "1.3116666572168469"
},
{
reason: "200.0",
Duracion: "1.1416666507720947"
}
]

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: reason is not defined(anonymous function) @ (index):17m.extend.each @ jquery.js:2(anonymous function) @ (index):16m.Callbacks.j @ jquery.js:2m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.js:2x @ jquery.js:5m.ajaxTransport.send.b @ jquery.js:5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong variable name (Duration != Duracion) and you need to refer to val as an object to get the data from it.

Change your JavaScript code to

```
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
    $('ul').append('<li Reason="' + val.reason + '">' + val.Duracion + '</li>');
});
```

Also change

```
@$myarray = getArraySQL($query);
```

To

```
$myarray = getArraySQL();
```

Comment: I understand this better.


Thanks a lot!!! now it works and also I understand why.

Comment: 211.0-3.6302777701057494
201.0-1.3116666572168469
200.0-1.1416666507720947

Answer (score 1):

Solution,

Instead of `reason` while looping, use `val.reason`

#### What are the other issues?

In `php.php`, you call `getArraySQL` method with `$query` as a parameter but the function `getArraySQL` definition does not take any parameters and builds some query by itself.

Morever, you are supressing errors by appending `@` in front of `$myarray =getArraySQL($query);`

Things to look into,

- Error suppression
- Naming files, `php.php` does not make sense. It never did, it never will.

Comment: Thanks, I will step by step according to yor Answer. I´ll notice You on a few minutes

Comment: I should give the query another name?

Notice: Undefined variable: query in C:\xampp\htdocs\byp1\dbquery1.php on line 28
[{"reason":"211.0","Duracion":"3.6302777701057494"},{"reason":"201.0","Duracion":"1.3116666572168469"},{"reason":"200.0","Duracion":"1.1416666507720947"}]

Comment: Damn, `@$myarray =getArraySQL($query);` but where in the name of god have you declared a variable `$query`. If you say inside function `getArraySQL` you need to check variable scopes.